# Fastest way to find a cross in a matrix

Tags: matlab

[image]

---

**Definition:** 
A(i, j) = 1 is a midpoint of a cross if the elements 
A(i-1, j) = 1 
A(i+1, j) = 1 
A(i, j+1) = 1 
A(i, j-1) = 1. 
Together the elements and the midpoint form a cross in a matrix A, where A is at least a 3-by-3 matrix and *i*, *j* ∈ ℕ\{0}.

---

Suppose the image above is the 8-by-8 matrix A with natural numbers 1, 2, 3 ... as elements. From this definition the matrix has a total of 3 crosses. The crosses have their midpoints on A(2,2), A(5, 4) and A(5, 5).

What I want to do is write a function that finds the number of crosses in the matrix A. I have an idea but I'm not sure it's the most optimal one. Here's the pseudocode for it:

```
ITERATE FROM row 2 TO row 7
    ITERATE FROM column 1 TO column 8
        IF current element contains 1
            INCREMENT xcount by 1
            IF xcount >= 3
                CHECK IF counted 1:s is part of a cross
        ELSE IF xcount IS NOT 0
            SET xcount to 0
```

The idea is to iterate through every column from row 2 to row 7. If I find 3 consecutive 1:s on the same row I immediately check if the 1:s belongs to a cross. This should work, but imagine having a very large matrix A - how efficient would this code be in that situation? Couldn't this problem be solved using vector notation?

Any answer is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not really define what a cross is. Does `ones(3,4)` contain two crosses?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I've added a definition. ones(3, 4) contain two crosses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not near matlab at the moment, but this is what I'd do. Assuming `A` is binary (has only 0'a and 1's):

```
 crs=[0 1 0 ; 1 1 1 ; 0 1 0];           % a minimal "cross" filter
 C=conv2(A,crs./sum(crs(:)),'same');    % convolve A with it
 [x y]=find(C>0.9);                     % find x,y positions of the crosses by looking
                                        % for peak values of C
```

so you basically convolve with a "minimal" (normalized) cross (`crs`) and look for peaks using `max`. `x` and `y` are the coordinates of your cross positions. No need to use for loops, just the built in (and pretty fast) 2d convolution, and the `max` function.

The threshold condition `C>0.9`, is just to illustrate that there's need to be a threshold that is weighted by intensity of `crs`. In this case I have normalized `crs` in the colvolution line (`crs/sum(crs(:))`) so if `A` is a binary matrix as in the example, you find that the convolution of the minimal normalized cross will leave the value of the pixel where the cross is at `1`, whereas other pixels will be less than 1 (that's why I arbitrarily chose 0.9) . So you can replace the threshold to `C==1`, if it's always a binary.

Another way to visulize the position of the cross is just to look at `C.*(C==1)`. This will generate a matrix the size of `A` with `1`s only where the crosses were...

### EDIT:

For maximal speed, you may consider writing it as a one liner, for example:

```
[x y]=find(conv2(A,[0 1 0 ; 1 1 1 ; 0 1 0]./5,'same')==1);
```

Comment: Beat me! I would replace `>0.9` by `==nnz(crs)`

Comment: in theory it should be `==1` if `crs` is normalized, that's why the filter is `crs./sum(crs(:))`, I'm just not sure about whether `A` is always binary or not etc...

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you were normalizing `crs`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I realized my question wasn't correctly formulated. I've made an update on the question. I hope this doesn't change the  solution you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @user1497133: Regarding your updated question, this answer is exactly what you want. For the alternative where a cross requires the diagonal neighbours to be zero, starting with `crs=[-1 1 -1 ; 1 1 1 ; -1 1 -1]; ` would be required.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Excited for tomorrow when im going to compare the speed of the solutions.

Comment: What if I would like the elements that form a cross to be any natural number 1, 2, 3, ... ? Would this work then? E.g. if I replace the ones in the matrix A with threes.

Comment: just understand what a convolution is and you see what will happen. The idea using it is when you know a-priory what your signal looks like. Then convolving it with a "matched filter" ensures that the result will be a peak in the convolution map. For any natural number you can binarize the matrix (i.e. use `logical(A)`), but here I assume I understand how you define a cross,  If you want to ask a more specific question please rephrase the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Using bit masks:

```
ux = [false(size(A,1),1) (A(:,3:end) & A(:,2:end-1) & A(:,1:end-2)) false(size(A,1),1)]
uy = [false(1,size(A,2)); (A(3:end,:) & A(2:end-1,:) & A(1:end-2,:)); false(1, size(A,2))]
u = ux & uy
[x y] = find(u)
```

Comment: sure, for the special case of a binary filter such as the  "cross",  a logical condition will work fine, and maybe even faster +1