# Create matching template to detect image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to detect numbers in a Sudoku Grid using a template image.I am doing this in MATLAB.
[image: Scanned image]
    For example I have cropped '1' image and I need to use this image so as to detect other '1' present in the image. I am not going anywhere with this. Please help me. Ho

Comment: use `conv2`, and find peaks in the convolution, see for example ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638416/fastest-way-to-find-a-cross-in-a-matrix/28638497#28638497  ,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178852/identifying-corners-in-a-jigsaw-puzzle/23179373#23179373

Comment: Please stop making vandalizing edits to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have choosen the hardest number to start with, because if you use the typical template matching approach (using [`xcorr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html), [`normxcorr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html), or [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)) then you're going to accidentally match well with the horizontal and vertical lines as well as the upright part of the 4's.

To better demonstrate the basic process, I will start with number 7 since that is a little bit more unique of a shape.

[image]

First we want to load the images in as grayscale (extract just the red channel)

```
board = imread('board.jpg')
board = board(:,:,1);

template = imread('seven.jpg')
template = template(:,:,1)
```

In order to detect the template in the image, we can use [normalized 2D cross-correlation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). This method essentially shifts the template over the image and at each shift computes the correlation between the template and the image.

```
C = normxcorr2(template, board);
figure; imshow(C);
```

[image]

As you can see, the correlation values are high (white) when the template matches well (where the 7's are) and dark where it doesn't match well.

As you can easily see there are three main peaks in the resulting correlation matrix (knowing how many 7's there are is a little difficult).

The nice thing about correlations is that the values actually *mean* something. So we can set a cutoff for "good". For the sake of an example let's go with 0.7 as our cutoff;

```
[row, col] = find(C >= 0.7);

hold on
plot(col, row, 'y.');
```

[image]

There are actually 35 points at which `C` is greater than 0.7; however, they clearly cluster into three groups.

You could cluster these by a variety of ways. Then take the average center of each group.

**Now to deal with the more difficult problem of 1's**

If we look at the result of normalized cross-correlation with the one image, we get something like this.

[image]

As you can see, you pick up the ones but you also pick up all of the vertical lines. Thankfully we can detect those fairly easily using a vertical white line and 2D convolution

```
vline = ones(size(board,1), 1);
lineimage = conv2(board, vline, 'same');
```

[image]

You could then use `lineimage` as a weighting for your correlation values so that then you only return "true" peaks.

```
% Normalize
lineimage = lineimage ./ max(lineimage(:));
C = C .* lineimage;
```

We now can see the true ones a little better.

[image]

We can then use a similar method as before to draw some dots (note the lower cutoff correlation value).

```
[row, col] = find(C >= 0.4)
p = plot(col, row, 'y.')
```

[image]

As you can see we picked up a 4 but it's worth a shot.

**While that was a great exercise, you could also easily use the built-in [ocr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html) functionality of MATLAB**

Comment: For the clustering you could even do something very simple like computing the distance between all points and set a cutoff for if two points are within that distance they can be considered the same.

Comment: For clustering, QT clustering or something similar could work. https://github.com/suever/regionalDyssynchrony/blob/master/qtClustering.m

Comment: @DipitMalhotra You will want to create a template for each, and then loop through the same process with each of them. Also you have a decent amount of knowledge that should help you 1) you can have a MAX of 9 of a number and 2) two numbers can't occupy the same square.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you start by partitioning the image into 9 x 9 (81) smaller images, and processes each of those smaller images separately.

I just completed an online Machine Learning class (https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) and recognizing handwritten numbers was one of the weekly assignments. This assignment was rather easy using Neural Networks, using the learning data and the programming template that was provided. A new session of this course begins Monday, February 8. There is no cost. You will learn a lot. I highly recommend it. (It would be a violation of the honor code for me to share my assignment with you.)